# Export live messages out of MS Teams into another Office application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, ms-office, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have got a question concerning the export of live messages out of MS Teams into antother office application. Is it possible to export messages (live) out of a teams chat into another office application to analyse them there?

I thought about using Microsoft Graph, but I am not sure if MS Graph is the right tool to solve my issue.
If it is what would be the first steps to do so?

Many thanks,
Lennart

Comment: MS Graph also supports webhook through which we could subscribe for real-time notification of channel messages and chat messages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Yes i agree with Prakash above to create a webhook. In addition, you can try subscription/notifications to see if it fits your scenario.